# How to set value of i2c PCA9570 gpio expander as early as possible during Linux boot?

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux, gpio, device-tree

I have written a working driver for the PCA9570.  Its four outputs are set (and read back) via Linux's GPIO subsystem. e.g.

```
root@armbox:/sys/class/gpio# echo 508 > export
root@armbox:/sys/class/gpio# echo 509 > export
root@armbox:/sys/class/gpio# echo 510 > export
root@armbox:/sys/class/gpio# echo 511 > export
```

The problem is that the chip starts with its outputs high.  https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9570.pdf section 8.1.

```
root@armbox:/sys/class/gpio# cat gpio508/value 
1
root@armbox:/sys/class/gpio# cat gpio509/value 
1
root@armbox:/sys/class/gpio# cat gpio510/value 
1
root@armbox:/sys/class/gpio# cat gpio511/value 
1
```

I can manually set them low from userspace, after boot.  e.g.

```
root@armbox:/sys/class/gpio# echo 0 > gpio510/value 
root@armbox:/sys/class/gpio# cat gpio510/value 
0
```

How can I set the chip's outputs low as early as possible during the boot sequence?

I can hack my own driver to do this, during `pca9570_probe()`, but that feels very hacky.  `pca9570_probe()` currently reads the values from the chip.

```
static int pca9570_probe(struct i2c_client *client,
                   const struct i2c_device_id *id)
{
    ...

    ret = pca9570_readb(chip, &chip->reg);
    if (ret)
        goto out_failed;

    return 0;

out_failed:
    if (chip->client)
        i2c_unregister_device(chip->client);

    return -1;
}
```

Is there a correct way in Linux to specify GPIO values during boot, rather than hacking a driver?

P.S. The dts clause is:

```
            pca9570: pca9570@48 {
                            compatible = "pca9570";
                            reg = <0x24>;
                            gpio-controller;
                            #gpio-cells = <4>;
            };
```

Comment: Side note: AFAIU the driver `gpio-pca953x` serves for PCA957[45]. You may check if it easily can be extended to support PCA9570.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'GPIO hogging' mechanism as described in [DeviceTree gpio binding documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt). Quoting basic information:

> GPIO hogging is a mechanism
>   providing automatic GPIO request and configuration as part of the
>   gpio-controller's driver probe function.

For example, we have this definition in our device tree for our gpio expander:

```
gpio_expander: tca6424a@22 {
        compatible = "ti,tca6424";
        reg = <0x22>;
        [...] /* some other gpio expander configuration */

        lcd-rst {
                gpio-hog;
                gpios = <7 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
                output-low;
        };
};
```

You don't need to extend your driver, it is part of the gpio subsystem.

Comment: Thanks, that's an ideal answer.